# Handling fraction when converting from base M to base N?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert any number from any base M to another base N, what I have done in my code is to convert the inserted number from base N to decimal then convert it from decimal to base M. My code works fine for any base less than 37, but it's not handling fractions. For instance, if the input has fractions like 1001.01 the conversion doesn't come out correctly. Can anyone help me figuring my mistake?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

int charToVal(char curChar)
{
    char convArray[] = 
    {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    for(int i=0;i<37; ++i)
    {
        if(curChar==convArray[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

char valToChar(int val)
{
    char convArray[] = 
    {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    if(val <37 && val>=0)
    {
        return convArray[val];
    }
    return ' ';
}

bool convertToDecimal(char * gdstr, int length, int inConvertor, int & decimal)
{
    int factor = 1;
    decimal=0;
    std::cout << length;
    for(int i=length-1; i >=0; --i)
    {
        int curVal(charToVal(gdstr[i]));
        decimal +=  factor*curVal;
        factor*=inConvertor;
    }
    std::cout << decimal << std::endl;
    return true;
}
bool convertFromDecimal(int  decimal, int outConvertor, char * outString, int & length)
{
    int fact = 1;
    length=0;
    while (decimal > 0)
    {
        fact = decimal%outConvertor;        
        char curChar(valToChar(fact));
        outString[length] = curChar;
        decimal/=outConvertor;        
        length++;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{


    char out[50];
    int outLeng=0;
    int decVal;
    int inLeng;
    std::cout << "Length of InFormat " ;
    std::cin >>  inLeng;
    char any[inLeng];
    for(int i = 0; i< inLeng; i++)
    {std::cout << "In Format Num "; 
        std::cin >> any[i];}
    int inType;
    std::cout << "In Format Tyep" ; 
    std::cin >> inType;
    int outtype;
    std::cout << "Out Format Tyep" ; 
    std::cin >> outtype;
    convertToDecimal(any, inLeng, inType, decVal);
    convertFromDecimal(decVal, outtype, out, outLeng);
    std::cout << std::endl << "out Type is :" << std::endl;
    for(int i = outLeng-1; i >=0; --i)
    {
        std::cout << out[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: try using the debugger

Comment: _"the conversion doesn't come out correctly"_ - You should include the output you get and what output you were expecting _in_ your post.

Comment: You can do this directly, no need to go via decimal. Your question isn't about floating-point, it is about handling the fractional part.

Comment: how to do it directly?

Comment: Your two `convArray`'s are (marginally) wasteful because they are initialized in each function on each call.  You could make them `static const char convArray[]` at file scope, so that they are initialized once, at program startup, and simply used thereafter.

Comment: BTW, your intermediate type is `int`, so you're actually converting to/from *binary* not decimal. You only think it's decimal because you're used to the I/O functions doing the conversion for you.

Comment: Anyway, to maybe steer you on the right track: How *should* your code handle decimal points? Maybe should it actually be able to detect a decimal point character? What's different about the digits to the right of the decimal point as opposed to the ones to the left?

Comment: I think digits at the right should be multiplied by a negative power and the left part by positive. But I don't know how to make my program separates left and right part

Comment: How to do it directly? Well, you're already converting from *M* to decimal, and from decimal to *N*, so you already know how to do radix conversion. Just do the first step with *N* instead of 10 as the target radix, or the second step with *M* instead of 10 as the source radix.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to realize is that unlike integers fractional values can't always be represented in arbitrary bases with a finite number of digits. For example, the value 0.1 decimal can't be represented exactly in binary. Thus, when converting from an origin base with an exact value, you may need to use an approximation in another base. Specifically, if the target base does not include all prime factors of the source base, there are values which can't be represented accurate: for example, all binary fractions can be represented using decimal fractions but not all decimal fractions can be represented using binary fractions.

There is a pair of algorithms used to do two conversions. They are primarily targeted to converting a base 10 floating point value to a base 2 floating point value and back to the original base 10 value. The round trip restores the original value assuming the original didn't use too digits for the approximated value. The algorithms are presented in two seminal papers:

1. [How to Read Floating Point Numbers Accurately](http://www.cesura17.net/~will/professional/research/papers/howtoread.pdf) for the conversion from an exact to an approximated representation.
2. [How to Print Floating Point Numbers Accurately](http://kurtstephens.com/files/p372-steele.pdf) for the conversion from an approximated representation back to the original value.

Specifically the second conversion isn't as fast as you'd like it to be and there are improvements, in particular Florian Loitsch's [Grisu](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/florian-loitsch/printf.pdf). The algorithms are somewhat non-trivial. [Double Conversion](https://code.google.com/p/double-conversion/) is an implementation of the algorithms.